# How do I add a kernel boot parameter on live session itself?

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I need to add boot parameter "pci=noaer" on my live persistent usb itself. Applying this command in terminal gave a error.

```
sudo update-grub
```

Error: `/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of 'aufs'`.

I am first time Linux user, my laptop is gone for repairs and I borrowed my dad's laptop. I just wanted to browse the internet. It took me 8 days and I am still not able to achieve this basic task. Actually I am having issue with wifi card "rtl8723be" ,its a known bug.

"sys.log" and "kernal.log" floads with pcie error and it basically fills my pendrive with those two large files which makes its unbootable. At this moment I hate Linux with passion. I willing to learn and understand more about Linux but I  need this system to work urgently. Please guys help me.

Comment: On live usb itself.

Comment: How did you created your USB?

Comment: through this software - "Universal USB Installer".

Comment: Did you consider any persistent storage for your USB?

Comment: Thanx, and yes 4gb persistent.

Comment: I will try this and post back asap.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install grub` this works and i am able to update grub.

Comment: Thanx, but there is new problem now. What should i do next. Post it here or make a new post.

Comment: Sent what you did to solve your problem as an answer so it will help others with similar problem ;-)

Comment: Hi! Ravexina can u please come here and help. [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919688/missing-grub-cfg-file-instead-have-menu-lst-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: I saw your other question, sadly I'm not really familiar with Live disks schema :/

Comment: sir, can u make sense of this- [link](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1003982.html) this can solve the main error i am getting which is - `/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of 'aufs'`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just needed to install grub.

```
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get install grub
```

This command works fine now -

```
sudo update-grub
```