# missing grub.cfg file instead have menu.lst on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

want to add boot parameters(pci=nomsi) permanently on live ubuntu session itself with persistent.

Able to add it through using this command-
`gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`

But system  still doesnt start with those parameters.
I think its something related to not having "grub.cfg" file.

This is my first ever linux experience. I am complete noobie, i am trying to get this system up and running for 9 days. Please guide me through this problem.

Previous questions and how i get here- 
1.[link1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919483/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter-on-live-session-itself)
2.[link2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919615/make-boot-parameters-permanent-on-live-session-itself)
3.[link3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919659/ubuntu-is-not-booting-up-with-desired-parameter)

Comment: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info  If somehow you managed to install grub legacy over grub2 that would be the only way to get menu.lst. Boot-Repair's advanced mode as a total uninstall/reinstall of grub2 option.

Comment: yup i have legacy grub insalled

Comment: I've updated my answer please check it again

Comment: Did you try running Boot-Repair's advanced mode to uninstall grub and reinstall grub2? Then you will have grub.cfg and /etc/default/grub.

Answer (score 0):

For add kernel parameters you can editing the `/etc/default/grub` file and then add your kernel parameters:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Then you can see somethings like this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

You must to add `pci=nomsi` after `quiet splash` as kernel parameters and then save the changes by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>.

You can check the changes by this command:

```
cat /etc/default/grub
```

After changes you must see somethings like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nomsi"
```

And as the last step, you must apply changes by this command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

**Update:** If you see this error `/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of aufs'.` , It may be helpful to remounting and remapping.

So do this steps:

As the first step check your Ubuntu and your boot partitions with this command:

```
lsblk
```

It may be mounted at `/` and `boot` mountpoints.

Then after booting the **live disk**, mount the Ubuntu partition to `/mnt` with this command:

```
sudo mount /dev/sd*# /mnt
```

For example:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda8 /mnt
```

So `/dev/sd*#` is mounted to your Ubuntu partition.

If you have a separate `/boot` partition, you'll need to mount it in `/mnt/boot` as well:

```
sudo mount /dev/sd*# /mnt/boot
```

For example:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot
```

where `/dev/sd*#` is updated to your `/boot` partition.

This should mount it with enough access to get the canonical path if needed, but we'll likely not need this.

To finish up, just update grub with the correct root and target:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdX
```

where `/dev/sdX` is the **disk(not the partition)** where we want GRUB.

For example:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

As an alternative way you can use `boot-repair` in **live disk**:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Comment: `sudo update-grub` gives error- `/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `aufs'.`

Comment: @Jason I've updated my answer please check it again